# Changing iPhone's language settings effect on my App

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization, arabic

I'm working on an app that's support Arabic Language. 
My problem is : when the user change the language of the iPhone to **Arabic** all the menu and component of my app changed in a very bad way.
How to prevent my app to take the iPhone's language settings?

Answer (score 0):

In Project Info uncheck use base internationalization.
and if u want to add Language then click on + sign to add.see i have upload image 
[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer.
but not that's what i want. 
I want my app support arabic if the user change the language form the app. 
but I don't want changing the language form the iPhone effect on my app.